# Masking original url in address bar

Tags: php

I want to show content of original url but with masked url in address bar.

For example I want to see 'www.google.com' in browser but in address bar 'www.blablabla.com'.

Comment: That would be a huge security risk. The most you can do is append with javascript.

Comment: Take a look at `window.location.search` within JavaScript.

Comment: You can usually use a frame for this, though some sites detect being "framed" and will redirect using JavaScript. Try it with Google, they probably permit it. Bear in mind though that frames are seen as obsolete mark-up.

Comment: Why on Earth do you want to do this? Phishing instantly comes to mind!

Comment: google site was just an example. URL can be of any site.

Comment: Dale:- so, that when visitor redirects on any other url, they just can't copy and paste that url, because I am using it with Konami codes (cheat codes in site)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://hasin.me/2008/11/29/host-your-blog-anywhere-using-this-10-line-proxy-script/).

Comment: use frames should help

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im : if I change in .htaccess file, wouldn't this affect my original site ?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: that's causing unnecessary traffic, but it does get the job done :)

Comment: @Dave You can implement caching and reduce caching.

Comment: @Khushboo No. Why it would affect original site? Do both site exists in same folder?

Answer (score 2):

There is one magic file in etc. called hosts

```
/etc/hosts
```

You can edit this file and put the line

```
www.google.com www.blablabla.com
```

When someone enters the site www.google.com the site www.blablabla.com will be shown. On this site you can recieve content of page with **curl** or `file_get_contents()`. The line above should be added to every client's machine.

The other solution is to use Frames in html. And the last one is to change DNS with proper entry. You can create your own DNS server and assign google.pl to your server.  Then if you have router you can change DHCP settings to make users connect to your DNS server.

**However, this is only for learning purpose. Don't abuse it!**

It smells to me like phising.

Comment: `When someone enters the site www.google.com the site www.blablabla.com` - It should be added that this needs to be done on **every client** that you want the custom DNS entry to work on.

Comment: Yep it's true @h2ooooooo

Comment: @Robert : google.com is just an example. Admin can enter any url which will save into database.

Comment: It's usually done for schools who want a web interface for their printers, the website could be called `printsv/`.

Comment: @khushboo yes he can. Dave chen, the best solution is to create DNS server and assign computers to this DNS server.

Comment: Can anybody give me full step-wise information? Any tutorial, anything. I am new to this type of thing.

Comment: you're lazy, you've been given a clues now you can google these things and easily find solutions. There are a lot of tutorials in net.

Answer (score 0):

Any site? No, major security threat. You can use iframes to display some other site on YOUR domain, but not the other way round. Search engines and the like do not like this sort of behavior though.